# CORS on EC2 TOMCAT 7

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2, cors

I am trying to do an ajax call from the ad client (js) to Ec2 Tomcat7.

I follow the steps here to enable CORS on tomcat7.

http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html

it gives me

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ec2-122-248-194-3.ap-southeast-1.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/Cocacard/FrontServlet. Origin "http://192.168.2.3" is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

I also tried in my server side servlet code,

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

without luck.

Any one runs into this b4 for ec2 tomcat7?

regards
hammer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to configure your "CORS Filter" in web.xml, with following:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>http://192.168.2.3</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
```

Comment: How allowOrigin can be parametrized in this example? For me hardcoding IP or domain in web.xml is unacceptable.